# Correct output not received from AJAX POST call

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, post

Have been trying to fix this for two days now and I just can't work it out.. I have created a jsp file containing a simple form. When I submit the form it posts the form data to `/CommentController` where the output should be returned and displayed in a `div` underneath the form.

The AJAX call appears to be successful but it returns the entire html of index.jsp instead of the output from the CommentController. Why is it doing this?

I am using `eclipse`, `Jsp` and `servlet`.

[image]

----------If I navigate to the CommentController it outputs what looks like the majority of the index.jsp file!?!?!?
[image]

Here is the form webpage:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8" import="com.servlet.explore.*, java.util.*, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, java.text.ParseException" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>p</title>
    <meta name="description" content="p">
    <meta name="author" content="Chris Mepham">
    <BASE href="http://localhost:8080/chrismepham/read-post.jsp">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullPost.css" type="text/css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<form id="commentForm">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name" required="required">
    <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Enter your comment here (max. 500 characters)" required="required"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="commentSubmit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#commentSubmit").click(function(e){
        var postData = $("#commentForm").serializeArray();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url : "CommentController",
                    data : postData,
                    dataType : "text",
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                            $("#result").text("<p>Success: </p>" + data);

                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                    {
                        $("#result").text("<p>ss"+errorThrown+textStatus+jqXHR+"</p>");
                    }
                });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    });
});
```

---

and CommentController.java file:

```
package com.servlet.explore;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CommentController
 */
@WebServlet("/CommentController")
public class CommentController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    PreparedStatement prep;
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public CommentController() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text");
       response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       response.getWriter().write("w0w00ww0w0");
    }
}
```

Comment: firstly, use `$("#result").html("<p>Success: </p>" + data);` instead of `$("#result").text(...`

Comment: @crm what is your expected output then?

Comment: @Jai `response.getWriter().write("w0w00ww0w0");`

Comment: Issue is in your servlet(CommentController) it is redirecting to index.jsp. Are you using any filter which may be intercepting while accessing the 'CommentController' Servlet. Check your web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a `urlrewriter` rule that exists.

```
<rule>
   <from>^/([a-zA-Z\-]+)$</from>
   <to>/index.jsp?category=$1</to>
</rule>
```

The above rule was redirecting the `POST` to the index.jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a slight mistake. You need to replace the target HTML rather than assigning text to that i.e

```
$("#result").html("<p>Success: </p>" + data);
```

Instead of:

```
$("#result").text("<p>Success: </p>" + data);
```

Comment: That just outputs the same thing in html form. It should just out put `w0w0w0w0`.

Comment: Try printing your text using println() instead of write() and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

```
response.setContentType("text");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.getWriter().write("w0w00ww0w0");
```

replace this with

```
   response.getWriter().println("w0w00ww0w0");
```